# Provision for ordering of parameters on redirection of URL

Tags: apex, visualforce, url, redirect

I am simply redirecting to a public page from apex using a method of pagereference return type. There are certail parameters that I need to pass during that redirection. The problem is that the service to which redirection is happening is demanding the parameters to be sent in a particular order only. However, from salesforce redirection is happening by having all the parameters arranged in alphabetical order only, even if I manually arrange the parameters in the order the client is requesting. What can be done here? Is there a provision for ordering of parameters? My code is below :

```
PageReference page = new PageReference(url);
page.getParameters().put('offerId',offerId);
page.getParameters().put('quickRenewal',quickRenewal);
page.getParameters().put('renewalRequestedBy',renewalRequestedBy);
page.getParameters().put('subId',subId);
page.getParameters().put('check',encryptedString);
System.debug('page url configuration'+page);
return page;
```

But the output is that on the landing page, 'check' parameter always appears as the first parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps are *unordered* collections, so the parameters can be ordered any way the platform chooses. And unfortunately, it chooses to be lexicographical by key name. This happens even if you put them directly in the URL:

```
PageReference ref = new PageReference('https://www.google.com/?q5=value1&q2=value2');
System.debug(ref.getUrl());
// Output: https://www.google.com/?q2=value2&q5=value1
```

Since this is the behavior, I don't see any workaround for this, aside from manually redirecting:

```
public String getRedirectUrl() {
   return 'https://whatever.com/?' +
     'q5=' + EncodingUrl.urlEncode('value1') + '&' +
     'q2=' + EncodingUrl.urlEncode('value2');
}
```

...

```
<script>
  let url = "{!JSENCODE(redirectUrl)}";
  window.location.href = url;
</script>
```

There will be some additional work to make this operational, but that's the basics.

Or, of course, you could redirect to a third-party server to re-order the parameters, as well. It's unfortunate, but any workaround isn't going to come easy at this point.